# use_native_modules! skipped the react-native dependency 'react-native-beacons-manager'. No podspec file was found

Tags: ios, react-native

Android works perfect but ios get an error.

Version : 
   "react": "16.9.0",
   "react-native": "0.61.5",
Steps Followed :

- `npm install react-native-beacons-manager --save`
- `cd ios && pod install`

Getting the following error :

```
    use_native_modules! skipped the react-native dependency 'react-native-beacons-manager'. No podspec file was found.  
    - Check to see if there is an updated version that contains the necessary podspec file
    - Contact the library maintainers or send them a PR to add a podspec. The react-native-webview podspec is a good example of a package.json driven podspec. See
    https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/react-native-webview.podspec
    - If necessary, you can disable auto-linking for the dependency and link it manually. See
    https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md#how-can-i-disable-autolinking-for-unsupported-library
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like react-native-beacons-manager doesn't support auto linking

`react-native.config.js` (create this file at the root of project)

```
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'react-native-beacons-manager': {
      platforms: {
        ios: null
      },
    },
  },
};
```

and manually link the package using

```
react-native link react-native-beacons-manager
```

Comment: when  is use this dependency  i get  "Null is not an object in Beacons.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();

Comment: Have you resolved this problem with "Null is not an object"? If yes, how you resolve this issue?